# Select using ifnull and subquery error SQL Error [1242] [21000]: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to get data from some subquery but it just return SQL Error [1242] [21000]: Subquery returns more than 1 row, is there something wrong with my code?

```
  SELECT
    u.id user_id, p.id user_profileid, p.firstname, p.lastname,
    IFNULL((SELECT SUM(ROUND((DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) / 365))) FROM employee_experience WHERE user_profileid = p.id GROUP BY user_profileid),0) AS experience,
    (SELECT jobtitle FROM employee_experience WHERE end_date IN (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM employee_experience GROUP BY user_profileid) AND user_profileid = p.id) AS last_jobtitle,
    IFNULL((SELECT lastsalary FROM employee_experience WHERE end_date IN (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM employee_experience GROUP BY user_profileid) AND user_profileid = p.id),0) AS last_salary
  FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN employee_profile p ON (u.id = p.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN employee_experience e ON (p.id = e.user_profileid)
  WHERE
     (u.roleid = '2') and (u.isverified = '1')
  GROUP BY
    u.id, p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

ifnull works only with 1 value and your subquery can return multiple values,
to fix this, you can use `limit 1` in your subqueries

```
    SELECT 
           u.id user_id, p.id user_profileid, p.firstname, p.lastname, IFNULL((SELECT
 SUM(ROUND((DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) / 365))) FROM
 employee_experience WHERE
 user_profileid = p.id GROUP BY
 user_profileid limit 1),0) AS experience,
 (SELECT jobtitle FROM
 employee_experience WHERE end_date
 IN (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM
 employee_experience GROUP BY
 user_profileid) AND user_profileid =
 p.id) AS last_jobtitle, IFNULL((SELECT
 lastsalary FROM employee_experience
 WHERE end_date IN (SELECT
 MAX(end_date) FROM employee_experience GROUP BY
 user_profileid) AND user_profileid = p.id
 limit 1),0) AS last_salary FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN employee_profile p ON (u.id =
 p.user_id) LEFT JOIN employee_experience e ON (p.id =
 e.user_profileid) 
WHERE 
     (u.roleid = '2')
 and (u.isverified = '1') 
GROUP BY u.id, p.id
```